# no rule for target "libm.tbd" when compiling on Mac

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, cmake

I am using Visual Studio Code with the CMake Tools extension to build my project.

When I try to compile the project, it gives the following error:

```
[build] make[2]: *** No rule to make target `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.1.sdk/usr/lib/libm.tbd', needed by `[...]'.  Stop.
```

The path it searches for is **not present**.
The SDK I have installed is `12.3`.
I tried using the following configure args:

```
-DCMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk
-DCMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=12.3
```

but that does not work (I have deleted CMake Cache prior)

What am I missing?